If the almost complex structure $I$(compatible with the metric of a Riemannian manifold) is integrable and $\omega$ is closed then they are parallel
$(M, g)$ : Riemannian manifold, $ I $ : an almost complex structure compatible with $g$ and $\omega $ the corresponding 2-form (that is, $ω^\flat = g^\flat \circ I$). Let $\nabla$ be the Levi-Civita connection on $ TM $.
I want to prove that if $I$ is integrable and $\omega$ is closed then they are parallel. Could you show me how to do it or tell me where I can find a proof?
Note:
I can taken as granted the following facts that I have already proven that might or not be useful for this:
1 $I$ is parallel with respect to the Levi-Civita connection if and only if $\omega $  is parallel, that is $$\nabla(IX) = I\nabla X ,\quad\forall X \in {\scr X} (M) \iff ∇\omega = 0$$
2 If $I$ is parallel it is integrable.
3 If $\omega$ is parallel, it is closed.

This is covered in Voisin's Hodge Theory and Complex Algebraic Geometry, I, Theorem 3.13.

@red_trumpet  Thanks for the suggestion. Any idea where I can also find these  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4895555/k%c3%a4hler-manifolds-properties-parallel-transp-induces-a-complex-linear-map-a-ri?noredirect=1#comment10446672_4895555   ? It is not in that book?
