Kähler manifolds properties: parallel transp induces a complex linear map & a Riemannian manifold is Kähler iff $Hol_\nabla(p) \subseteq U(T_pM)$?
$(M, g)$ : Riemannian manifold, $ I $ : an almost complex structure compatible with $g$ and $\omega $ the corresponding 2-form (that is, $ω^\flat = g^\flat \circ I$). Let $\nabla$ be the Levi-Civita connection on $ TM $.
I have the following facts to be used
1 $I$ is parallel with respect to the Levi-Civita connection if and only if $\omega $  is parallel, that is $$\nabla(IX) = I\nabla X ,\quad\forall X \in {\scr X} (M) \iff ∇\omega = 0$$
2 If $I$ is parallel it is integrable.
3 If $\omega$ is parallel, it is closed.
4 $I$ is integrable and $\omega$ is closed then they are parallel
How can I use these facts to conclude that
(a)in a Kähler manifold parallel transport along a curve $\gamma$ using the Levi-Civita connection gives rise to a complex linear map between $T_{\gamma(0)}M$ and $T_{\gamma(1)}M$ and
(b) a Riemannian manifold is Kähler if and only if $Hol_\nabla(p) \subseteq U(T_pM)$?
Notation:

$ U(T_pM)$ where $U(T_pM)$ denotes the unitary transformations of $T_pM$  that is, orthogonal and complex linear transformations of $T_pM$)
$Hol_\nabla(p)$ denotes the holonomy of the connection $\nabla$ at a point $p ∈ M$, that is $Hol_\nabla(p) = \{\tau_{\gamma}|\gamma : [0, 1] → M, \gamma(0) = \gamma(1) = p\}$. ,
Let $E \to M$ be a vector bundle and let $\nabla$ be a connection on $E$. $\tau_{\gamma}:E_{\gamma(0)}\to E_{\gamma(1)}$ denotes parallel transport along $\gamma$ for each path $\gamma$


You'll want to use the "Holonomy Principle": If $\sigma$ is a parallel tensor field on $M$, then $\sigma|p$ is fixed by the $\mathrm{Hol}\nabla(p)$-action.  Conversely, if a tensor $\sigma_0$ at $p \in M$ is fixed by the $\mathrm{Hol}_\nabla(p)$-action, then there exists a unique parallel tensor field $\sigma$ on $M$ for which $\sigma|_p = \sigma_0$.

@JesseMadnick Do you refer to (b)? (I just edited it to make clear the question has 2 parts)Could you elaborate on how to do that? That definition of holonomy is the first and only thing I know about holonomy, I am having a hard time putting it to use. So I don't use any of the facts 1 to 4?

I think you should first try to make the Holonomy Principle that @JesseMadnick refers to clear to yourself in the case of vector fields, i.e. that parallel vector fields correspond to holonomy invariant elements in the tangent space. Having understood that, you can employ the same principle to the induced connections on either $L(TM,TM)$ (for dealing with $I$) or on $\Lambda^2T^*M$ (for dealing with $\omega$), taking into account how the parallel transport for this induced connections relates to the parallel transport on $TM$.

@AndreasCap Do you know I can find an explanation of all this?

You can try the lecture notes available at https://impa.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/PM_39.pdf .

I believe you need the fact that $I$ is an isometry., i.e., $$g(IX,IY) = g(X,Y).$$
I believe you can start as follows: Given a curve $\gamma: I \rightarrow M$, let $F = (f_1, \dots, f_n)$ be a unitary frame that is parallel along $\gamma$. Now differentiate $$ g(f_j,f_k) = \delta_{ij} $$ to get a formula for $$\nabla_{\gamma'} F. $$ Using that formula, you should be able to what you want.

I am not sure why you haven't given the definition of a Kähler manifold that you would like to use. This is particularly relevant, since in my opinion the conditions 1. - 4. that you list are mainly needed in order to prove the equivalence of various possible definitions of being Kähler. The upshot of these considerations is that being Kähler can be equivalently defined via the fact that $I$ is parallel with respect to the Levi-Civita connection and hence also $\omega$ has to be parallel.
If this is an acceptable definition for you, then your question (a) is easy to answer: Recall that the parallel transport of tangent vectors along a curve $\gamma$ can be characterized as follows: Start with $X(0)\in T_{\gamma(0)}M$, find the unique curve $X(t)\in T_{\gamma(t)}M$ such that $\nabla_{\gamma'(t)}X(t)=0$ with the given initial condition $X(0)$ and then the parallel transport of $X(0)$ is given by $X(1)\in T_{\gamma(1)}M$. But then condition 1. implies that $\nabla_{\gamma'(t)}I(X(t))=I(\nabla_{\gamma'(t)}X(t))=0$. But from the definition above, this means that the parallel transport of the initial value $I(X(0))$ is $I(X(1))$ and since $X(0)$ is arbitrary, this says that the parallel transport is complex linear, hence answering your question (a).
For question (b) the holonomy principle mentioned in the comment of @Jesse_Madnick is indeed needed. Let me explain the idea for proving this in case of the Levi-Civita connection itself. There it says that parallel vector fields on $M$ are equivalent to $Hol_{\nabla}(p)$-invariant elements of $T_pM$ (if $M$ is connected). If $\nabla X=0$ then from above you can see that for any curve $\gamma$, $X(\gamma(1))$ is the parallel transport of $X(\gamma(0))$. Applying this to a closed curve $\gamma$ with $\gamma(0)=\gamma(1)=p$ readily shows that $X(p)=X(\gamma(0))$ is invariant under $Hol_{\nabla}(p)$. Conversely, one easily shows that if $X\in T_pM$ is invariant under $Hol_{\nabla}(p)$, then for any two curves $\gamma$ and $\tilde\gamma$ with $\gamma(0)=\tilde\gamma(0)=p$ and $\gamma(1)=\tilde\gamma(1)=q$, the parallel transports of $X$ along $\gamma$ and $\tilde\gamma$ give the same element of $T_qM$. (Basically, transporting $X$ along $\gamma$ to $q$ and then back to $p$ by running through $\tilde\gamma$ in the opposite direction, can be interpreted as a parallel transport along a closed curve, so it gives back $X$. Basic properties of the parallel transport then imply the claim.) Now you extend the element $X$ to a parallel vector field on $M$ by defining $X(p)=X$ and $X(q)$ to be the parallel transport of $X$ along any curve connecting $p$ to $q$.
Now the condition that $Hol_{\nabla}(p)\subset U(T_pM)$ is just a different wording for the fact that there is a complex structure $I$ on $T_p(M)$ for which $g$ is Hermitian and for which each element of $ Hol_{\nabla}(p)$ is a complex linear map. From this you could now construct an extension of $I$ to a parallel complex structure similarly to the case of vector fields above. (To define $I(q)$ choose a curve connecting $q$ to $p$, transport the a tangent vector $X\in T_qM$ to $p$, apply $I$ there and transport back to $q$. Similar arguments as above show that the resulting $I$ is parallel.)
More efficiently (but technically more demanding) you can use general results about connections. An almost complex structure $I$ on $M$ is a section of the vector bundle $L(TM,TM)$ which can be constructed from $TM$. This inherits a linear connection $\tilde\nabla$ (I am using this notation to be clear, usually all connections constructed in this way are denoted by the same symbol $\nabla$) from the Levi-Civita connection and $I$ being parallel then indeed means that $\tilde\nabla I=0$. The general results I referred to in particular say that $Hol_{\tilde\nabla}(p)\cong Hol(\nabla)(p)$ and the isomorphism is given by letting $A\in Hol(\nabla)(p)\subset GL(T_pM)$ act on the space $L(T_pM,T_pM)$ by $f\mapsto A\circ f\circ A^{-1}$. This shows that $Hol(\tilde\nabla)$ acts trivially on $I$ if and only if each element of $Hol(\nabla)(p)$ is complex linear with respect to $I$ and hence to $  Hol(\nabla)(p)\subset U(T_pM)$. As above, this is equivalent to $I$ extending to a section of $L(TM,TM)$ which is parallel for $\nabla$, which gives the alternative proof for (b).

Thanks for the answer. I didn't know there where many definitions. The one I have is that A Kähler manifold is a manifold M with a compatible pair of (integrable) complex and symplectic structures.

This is certainly true, but the properties 1. - 4. show that there are various ways to make the compatibility (and integrability) condition explicit.
